# Show reports based on user

Tags: powerbi

I am new to PowerBI. I have several stores. Now I want to make generic reports for all the stores. All the stores can see same reports. But the data for all the reports would be respective. That means particular store can see the data for itself. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do can be achieved with row level security.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls

Basically, you create roles for your reports which filter the data that is available to be seen by the people or groups that you assign to the roles.

E.g., if you had a Chicago store, you could create a "Chicago" role that filtered your data to only return parts of your data table (a filter specified like `Store[City] = "Chicago"`) and then you'd give the relevant individuals or groups from Chicago that role so they'd be able to see that data.