# How To Filter Data in Slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI and I have a visual (the slicer) that I want only to be displayed to users of a certain level.

The visual is a list of names but I want the visual to be available only to users of a certain level.

The column that contains these values is available to me through the data model but I can't drag it to the visual level filter because that feature doesn't exist in Power BI.

I can't apply a page level filter because that would restrict other data on the page that they should see.

Is there a workaround I can employ? Ideally I wouldn't want to change the data model.

Comment: You can show different sets of slicer options to different users, but I'm not sure if you can entirely disable a slicer based on the user.

Comment: This could be a useful workaround for me. Could you further detail what you mean please?

Comment: Row-level security can be used to show different users different subsets of the data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048590/show-reports-based-on-user/48055141

Comment: Thanks Alexis I think this might be the solution, I will have to change some back end code that generates the data model but looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is to hide another Slicer (the "pre-Slicer") behind the real Slicer. The real Slicer needs to have a non-transparent Background set. I mess with Interactions so the "pre-Slicer" only affects the real Slicer, and not all the other visuals on the page.

This is a really annoying limitation that will hopefully be lifted in a future release.  Please vote:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/12545673-visual-level-filtering-in-slicers